# Test for null values in C#

Tags: c#, dataset

If I do something like:

```
DataSet ds = GetMyDataset();

try
{
    string somevalue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["col1"];
}
catch
{
    //maybe something was null
}
```

Is there a good way to check for null values without using the try/catch? It's just that I don't care if the value in "col1" is null, OR if "col1" didn't exist, OR if there were no rows returned, OR if the table doesn't exist!

Maybe I should care? :)
Maybe try/catch is the best way of approaching this but I just wondered if there was another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, don't do a generic `catch`. That's a horrible practice. Catch the errors you're looking for.

Comment: Agreed. It was just thrown in as an example but it's sort of the same point - "don't use error handling to catch things that aren't really errors". I was just looking perhaps for any C# techniques/keywords related to this problem.

Comment: The Maybe monad seems like a good thing here. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/maybemonads.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [May be Monad](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/maybemonads.aspx) is best thing for this situation (Sample is from source):

> ```
> public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, 
>        Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
>        where TResult : class where TInput : class
> {
>   if (o == null) return null;
>   return evaluator(o);
> }
>
> string postCode = this.With(x => person)
>                       .With(x => x.Address)
>                       .With(x => x.PostCode)
> ```

for your case is similar to:

```
ds.With(x=>Tables[0]).With(x=>x.Rows).With(x=>x[0])...
```

you will create an extension class and use it without worring about null references, Also `Return` method is useful for you see link.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you made it work with DataSets? Tried to do something similar, but it breaks and gives me a `".. does not belong to the table Table"`, when I try it on this: `var test = daVideos.With(e => e.Tables[0]).With(e => e.Rows).With(e => e[0]).With(e=>e["Description"]).ToString();`

Answer (score 7):

It is kind of strange not to care about the Table or the Column.

It is a much more normal practice to expect `table[0].Rows.Count == 0` for instance.

And the best way to check for NULL values is with `if(...) ... else ...`.
The worst way is to wait for Exceptions (in whatever way).

Comment: I guess so. It's just that even after you write all the code that says "IF there is a dataset and IF there is a table and IF there is a ROW and IF there is a column" then the end result is still that you're only really interested in getting a value or not! Surely there's a way to increase code readability here?

Comment: "increase code readability here" - A better design, and maybe less DataSet. Your queries should always produce a (somewhat) defined type, so missing tables and columns can be avoided.

Comment: It was just an example. We've all come across the situation (not necessarily with datasets) where you have nested objects and have to say if obj !=null && obj.obj1 != null && obj.obj1.obj2 != null then get obj.obj1.obj2.value. Right?

Comment: @jqwha, there's no shortcut. It has often been requested for an operator of the form `?.` where you could say `a?.b`, and if `a` was null, this would not throw, the output would be defined as null or perhaps the default value of the type of `b`. But this is not presently part of the language nor am I aware if it is even a possibility for some future version.

Comment: Yes it happens. But when it's frequent or more than 2 levels deep I do start to look back at the design.

Comment: @Anthony - I thought so :(. Thanks.

Comment: @Henk - I know what you're implying but I never, ever buy the comment of "it's your design". It's way too academic to assume purity=simplicity and indeed the pursuit of academically pure designs often leads to vastly increased complexity

Comment: "to vastly increased complexity" - like in @redfilters answer? But note that I tried to admit the shades of gray.

Comment: There are FREQUENTLY situations where it is completely valid to say "somewhere in this deep hierarchy of objects, something may not be present, which means all the children will not be present, and it does NOT matter at all WHY they are not present, they just aren't because that is a logically consistent state of affairs". I'm just looking for the support in the language for something that happens ALL the time. We take it for granted that you can add 2 to -3 and get -1, without checking that any numbers are less than 0, right?

Comment: If you talk collections then LINQ handles this quite elegantly. In other contexts, you usually need an IF per level, but not necessarily all in one statement. Structured programming (stacking methods) still works.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (ds == null
    || ds.Tables == null 
    || ds.Tables.Count == 0
    || ds.Tables[0].Rows == null 
    || ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0
    || ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].IsNull("col1")
)
//there is no data...
...
```

Comment: Maybe start with `if (world == null || ...`

Comment: lol. They really need to build something recursive into the language.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure your code won't fail, you will actually have to check all the elements in the hierarchy, e.g.:

```
string someValue = "";

if (ds != null &&
    ds.Tables != null &&
    ds.Tables.Any() &&
    ds.Tables[0].Rows != null &&
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Any() &&
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["col1"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    someValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["col1"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataSet ds = GetMyDataset();

string somevalue = ds != null ? ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["col1"].ToString() : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to use the nullabel terinary '??', but I think the null that is being returned is a 'DBNull' and not 'null'.

The example would be...

```
string somevalue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["col1"] ?? "";
```

Comment: You are right that it will not be sufficient here. And that is the null coalescing operator, not a "terinary" or ternary. The one that everybody calls the ternary is the conditional operator, with the form `a ? b : c`.

Answer (score 1):

Do some checks :

```
string somevalue = String.Empty;
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Data.DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
                if (dt.Columns.Count>0 && dt.Columns.Contains("col1"))
                {
                   somevalue = dr["col1"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check them all for null (or other null types) one by one, beginning at the top (which is DataSet)

if( ds != null )
if( table!=null )
...

you can do it without, but your code will be much more susceptible to errors.

Comment: Yes but see my comment to Henk, above.

Answer (score 0):

From a maintenance point of view, what you are doing is very desirable.

Otherwise, you have to:   Check if DS is null, check to see if there are any tables in the DataSet, check to see if there are any rows in the table, check to see if the column exists, check to see if there is any data in the column.

It will certainly eliminates a lot of tedious code.

Answer (score 0):

What I've used in the past is a small wrapper of Null tests that return a default value. For example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Test DBValue for DBNull and return NullReplaceValue if DBValue is DBNull
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns NullReplaceValue if DBValue is DBNull</returns>
    public static string NullStr(object DBValue, string NullReplaceValue)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(DBValue, DBNull.Value)) {
            return NullReplaceValue;
        } else {
            return Convert.ToString(DBValue);
        }
    }
```

In use:

```
string somevalue = MyNullTests.NullStr(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["col1"], "Value was null");
```

Comment: As others have said string somevalue should be executed after you are sure rows exist first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make explicit that you do not care about all these things, meaning that you should handle each case explicitly:

```
if (ds.Tables.Count == 0)
  return null;

var table = ds.Tables[0];
if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
  return null;

if (!table.Columns.Contains("col1"))
  return null;

var row = ds.Rows[0];
if (row.IsNull("col1"))
  return null;

return row["col1"]
```

That is more code, but for me it communicates the intent more clearly.

Comment: But the "intent" is the retrieval of a value. I don't think we should be specifying all the things we DON'T care about. I'm not being a hacker or anything, but there's a balance to be struck I think?

Comment: I'd argue that the intent is to get the value while handling a bunch of special cases, "special" being the keyword here. Not caring about those things is important here because it's not usual. Of course you could (and probably should) put this in a method and reuse it, making the overhead of the additional code less relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are sending random, non validated datasets, indexes and names, you can do a helper method like this one:

```
public static Object GetDataSetValue(DataSet dataSet, int tableIndex, int rowIndex, string columnName)
{
    Object value = null;

    if (dataSet != null
        && tableIndex >= 0
        && tableIndex < dataSet.Tables.Count
        && rowIndex >= 0
        && rowIndex < dataSet.Tables[tableIndex].Rows.Count
        && dataSet.Tables[tableIndex].Columns.Contains(columnName))
    {
        value = dataSet.Tables[tableIndex].Rows[rowIndex][columnName];
    }

    return value;
}
```

And then just use something like `GetDataSetValue(ds, 0, 0, "col1")`.

Comment: What's your suggested alternative that will cover all the eventualities of required data access?

Comment: @jqwha change the method to what YOU would consider all eventualities and then just call it, I tried to include all the eventualities that you have mentioned, but you can use the idea to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

I hate having to deal with a data access layer that doesn't guarantee me a standard set of results: any given SQL query or stored procedure should **always** return the same result set schema. Dealing with empty sets (aka DataTables) is easy. Dealing with arbitrary missing object references...not so much.

The right answer is to fix your data access code so it returns a consistent schema.

Failing that, if I have to deal with code like that I do something like this:

```
DataSet   ds         = ExecuteStoredProcedure();
DataTable dt         = ( ds != null && ds.Tables != null ? ds.Tables[0] : null ) ;
DataRow   dr         = ( dt != null && dt.Rows   != null ? dt.Rows[0]   : null ) ;
object    o          = ( dr != null ? dr["someColumn"]) : null ) ;
string    someColumn = (string) colName ;
```

It's easy to debug either in the debugger or via logging. Give the set of 5 values, you can readily see what was present and what was missing. It makes it easy to see what assumption (constraint?) was violated.

Answer (score -1):

You check for DBNull.Value e.g.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["col1"] != DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: Problems with: Null dataset, no tables, no rows, etc.